# Is it possible to combine multiple WiFi?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, combine

Is it possible to use multiple WiFi at the same time to increase download speed, like combine them, or something like that?

I have a ZTE WiFi and a TP-LINK WiFi. Here's some lspci code

```
lspci | grep -i net
    03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
```

If it's possible, how do I do it?

I use Linux Mint Rosa.

Comment: short answer is no. There is a protocol called link-aggregation (802.3ad), but it work only on physical line (copper or fiber), and you have to set routing equipement properly. This however do no add speed, specially when downloading from a unique source.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically it can be done, but its a lot of work for little, if any gain in practice.

For a start, your PC shows you have 1 ethernet card and 1 WIFI adaptor.  This means that in order to get any benefit you will need to get another device to turn ethernet into WIFI.   This is, however, only the start of the issue.  ( and the rest of the post assumes you have either 2 WIFI devices in your computer, or an Ethernet to WIFI bridge of some sort )

In order to make this work you will need to -

1. Ensure that your frequencies don't overlap at all - and if they have
   different performance characteristics this can actually slow your
   throughput.  [ ie think of the neighbours ! ]
2. You will need a method of load balancing / aggregating / bonding the 
    connections - this is a large, fun topic, and either requires expensive
    hardware or significant compromises.

Unless you are a massochist or are doing this as a learning exersize or your time is valueless, you would be better off upgrading your equipment to the new 802.11n standard and buying more expensive equipment with more aerials/channels - this will give you the best utilization of the available spectrum, future proof your connection somewhat, be more power efficient and work better.    Alternatively, switch to using ethernet or look at an Ethernet over Power solution.

Comment: Actually, 802.11n is not really a new standard. The latest standard for which equipment is readily available is 802.11ac. The 802.11ad (60 GHz) standard will probably not be that popular since it can't go through walls, and neither can its (much) faster iteration, 802.11ay, which is expected to be approved in 2017.

Comment: Thanks for correcting that - I did mean 802.11ac (the op’s router is 802.11n !)